# Rigid Image Transformation MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rotation, translation

I have two face images and need to make sure that their eyes are aligned, so I wrote a script that allows me to get the coordinates of the eyes in the two pictures.

From there I was able to derive the rotation matrix R and translation vector T which represent the rigid planar transformation to apply to one image in order to align it to the second one.

However I don't know how can I apply the rotation and translation to the images brightness intensities and save the new version of the image.

I'm aware of these functions but can't really figure out how to use them given R and T.

- http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/projective2dclass.html
- http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/affine2dclass.html
- http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imwarp.html

I guess it should be something like this:

```
tform = <--- how to build this from R and T??
B = imwarp(A,tform)
```

Comment: Read my answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21819056/1586200) question. If you can't figure out the solution to your problem, please post a comment here.

Comment: On the other hand, if you have corresponding points (coordinates of eyes in both images), why don't you use `figeotrans` directly instead of calculating `T` and `R` and then calculating `TFORM` from that. I have explained how to use `fitgeotrans` in my above answer. Also, excellent documentation is available [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fitgeotrans.html).

Comment: @Parag - I see, your answer seems very useful, I wasn't aware of such a function. But so what would be my moving points vector? Would you mind detailing an answer also in this post? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Read up image stitching.

Answer (score 2):

`I = imread('cameraman.tif');
tform = maketform('affine',[1 0 0; .5 1 0; 0 0 1]);
J = imtransform(I,tform);
imshow(I), figure, imshow(J)`

you can change the 'affine' thing to projective and specify your projective transformation matrix accordingly

In your case, for a 2D image you can make the transformation as [R T; 0 0 1], where R is a 2x2 rotation matrix and T is a 2x1 translation matrix

Comment: I tried this but for some reason if I include the translation vector the output image gets all messed up. I.e. Dimensions become `1x1x3` instead of `1080x960x3`, any clue of what's going on?

Comment: could you upload the image and the transformation matrix you are using, you could also use [output, xdata, ydata] = imtransform(image,transform, 'XData',[1 width], 'YData',[1 height]); this would give you the output image and the position of the transformed pixels, just look into matlab help for imtransform